# How do I add arguments to a discord.py command?

Tags: python, discord.py

The code I have is:

```
weather = Weather(unit=Unit.CELSIUS)
location = weather.lookup_by_location('toronto')
forecasts = location.forecast

embed = (discord.Embed(title="-=-__THE WEATHER__-=-", color=0x15dbc7))
embed.add_field(name="Clouds", value=forecasts[0].text, inline=False) 
embed.add_field(name="Date", value=forecasts[0].date, inline=False)
embed.add_field(name="High", value=forecasts[0].high, inline=False)
embed.add_field(name="Low", value=forecasts[0].low, inline=False)
await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

How do I make it replace 0 with a variable which is put after the command?
The code I have which identifies the command is

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def weather(ctx)
```

The imports Im using are:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio
import random
import weather
from weather import Weather, Unit
```

Comment: Please include all of your imports so we can tell which libraries you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would pass that argument in the function definition, along with a [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) that lets `discord.py` know what type you want that value converted to.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def weather(ctx, index: int):
    weather = Weather(unit=Unit.CELSIUS)
    location = weather.lookup_by_location('toronto')
    forecasts = location.forecast

    embed = (discord.Embed(title="-=-__THE WEATHER__-=-", color=0x15dbc7))
    embed.add_field(name="Clouds", value=forecasts[index].text, inline=False) 
    embed.add_field(name="Date", value=forecasts[index].date, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="High", value=forecasts[index].high, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Low", value=forecasts[index].low, inline=False)
    await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

You would invoke this from Discord with something like `!weather 3`

Comment: Thank you so much! I wouldn't have figured that out, to be honest.

Comment: @WebCoder You're using version 0.16, but the [1.0 documentation includes documentation for the commands extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/index.html), most of which you can use for both versions.  It's worth reading.